# Why Task.Factory.StartNew().continuewith() Not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await

In Asp.Net MVC project I have an Asynchronus controller, wand I also have an action of type Task to implement Asynchronus functionality.

Well I have the following code,

```
Action startMethod = delegate() { CreateUserFunctionality(user.UserID); };
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(startMethod).ContinueWith(
                    t =>
                    {
                        return (ActionResult)RedirectToAction("Profile", "UserProfile");
                    });
```

And I also has, CreateUserFunctionality as

```
public void CreateUserFunctionality(int UsrId)
{
  if (UsrId !=0)
  {
     _userService.NewFunctionality(UsrId);
  }
}
```

I expect that the function will start the job, `CreateUserFunctionality` and returns the view for me which is written in `ContinueWith` function. However in my case that continuewith part always waits for the `CreateUserFunctionality` to complete. My aim was to return the view immediatly and not wait for `CreateUserFunctionality` to finish, as It should continue in background. Please let me find out what I am missing here.

Comment: How is this related to async-await?

Comment: Are you aware that `CreateUserFunctionality` may never complete properly? How would you recover from errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse it will wait because you are using `ContinueWith` method.If you don't want to wait just start your task, and leave it.Return your ActionResult immediately:

```
 var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(startMethod);
 return RedirectToAction("Profile", "UserProfile");
```

From [documentation:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Task.ContinueWith Method : Creates a continuation that executes
>   asynchronously **when the target Task completes.**

So it is working as expected.

Comment: Thanks Selman22, so what should be the type of actionresult, Currently I have it like, `public Task<ActionResult> UserUpdate(UserModel model)`. Do I need to remove the task from actionresult ?

Comment: Yes you can remove it

Comment: Thanks it worked like charm , and a good learning curve for me too.